# How to reset mat-select to initial state on click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I'm using `mat-select` with `mat-option` but I want to reset the `mat-option` selected when I click on a button. So instead of just set its value to `null`, I want the option without value to be displayed on the screen.

Example:

```
<div ngIf="listAccounts">
  <mat-select [(value)]="accountSelected">
     <mat-option>Select an option... </mat-option>
     <mat-option [value]="account" *ngFor="let account of listOfAccounts" (click)="yourFunction(account)"> 
       Account {{account.accountNumber}} Agency {{account.agencyNumber}} Digit{{account.digitNumber}} 
     </mat-option>
</mat-select>
<div>
<button (click)="listedAccounts = !listedAccounts"> Button </button>
```

Everytime I click on the button I want to `mat-option` go to `"Select an option..."` or an empty option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set empty value to `accountSelected` and change in `mat-option`

```
<mat-option value=''>Select an option... </mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the initialvalue to empty on Reset button click with multi select dropdowns

**HTML**

```
          <mat-select
            placeholder="{{ generalAppSettings?.filterVariables?.regionText }}"
            (selectionChange)="onRegionChange($event)"
            class="dropdownFilters"
            *ngIf="generalAppSettings.filterVariables.showRegionFilter"
            [(value)]="regionValue"
          >
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="
                let option of generalAppSettings.filterVariables?.continents
              "
              [value]="option.region"
            >
              {{ option.region }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>

          <mat-select
            placeholder="{{ generalAppSettings?.filterVariables?.countryText }}"
            (selectionChange)="onCountryChange($event)"
            class="dropdownFilters"
            *ngIf="generalAppSettings.filterVariables.showRegionFilter"
            [(value)]="initialCountryValue"
          >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countryValue" [value]="country">
              {{ country }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>

      <button
        class="btn btn--primary mat-button-cta"
        (click)="clearFilters()"
      >
        {{ generalAppSettings.filterVariables.resetInfo }}
      </button>
```

**Typescript**

```
clearFilters(): void {
    this.initialCountryValue = '';
    this.regionValue = '';
  }
```